# access file in php using a regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying a capture the flag game but I can only enter 50 characters in the url, I have found the name of the file but the name of the file is over 50 chars long (hence why its a challenge), the filename consists of [a-z][0-9] with a .key at the end of the file. I can execute almost all php functions via the url (as long as it doesn't go over 50 chars)

The name is unique with the .key at the end which is why I essentially wanted to use readfile(*.key);

Any suggestions?

note:

CTF is a game penetration testers play to practice their hacking skills...

I have cracked most of the web app along with source code but this is my final hurdle...

the source code its self restricts the url length to 50 characters (you know chars...strlen...)

I dont need to extend the url in the ini file it this is apart of the game.

Comment: "Capture the flag"? "Enter 50 characters"? What are you talking about, man?

Comment: Contact your hosts. I'm sure there is something within php.ini that lets you extend the allowed character amount in the URL.

Comment: @Amarnasan CTF is a game penetration testers play to practice their hacking skills... I have cracked most of the web app along with source code but this is my final hurdle... the source code its self restricts the url length to 50 characters (you know chars...strlen...)  I dont need to extend it this is apart of the game lol...

Comment: Maybe if you state the name of the file and the url you're trying to access...

Comment: I did but here is the name of the file 6729649877a54283f1d81ba094d9bfac.key (yes I know it isnt actually 50chars but the url get varible is greater than 50 chars...) either way I need to shorten it down to around 15 characters

Comment: like readfile(md5('th3key').'.key'); ?

Comment: @Amarnasan I cannot believe I didnt see that... omg I feel like an idiot! THANK YOU

Comment: Ok, now you can close this question by accepting the answer I just created out of my comment... and trust more in google as I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
readfile(md5('th3key').'.key');
```

It happens that the md5 function will return that string...

Comment: did you google the filename? just wondering on what keywords you used? md5 decoder?